# jQuery Splide, responsive height based on image

Tags: php, jquery, splidejs

We got this slide based on [Splide](https://splidejs.com/), used as article's photo slider, with attached second instance that act as a thumbnail paginator.

At the moment, it doesn't take care of the height of the pics, but just use the height of the taller image, making the thumbnails remain down when a 16/9 image is displayed, leaving a big white space unused.

[image]

Even if it is an huge layout swift, we need thumbnails staying glued to the bottom of the image, sliding up or down when an image change, can we achieve this situation?

Currently, my code is:

```
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<section id="main-carousel" class="splide" role="group" style="margin-top: 30px" >
    <div class="splide__track">
        <ul class="splide__list">
            <?php 
                $i = 0;
                foreach(get_field('gallery') as $image ) {
                    if ($i == 0) { $active = 'active'; } else { $active = '';}
                        echo '<li class="splide__slide" data-splide-interval="3000">';
                           echo '<div class="splide__slide__container" style="max-height: fit-content>';
                                echo '<a href="' . $image .'" data-lightbox="image-' . ($i + 1) . '">';
                                    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" style="width:100%" />';
                                echo '</a>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        echo '</li>';
                        $i++;
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br class="clear" />
    </section>
    <script>
        var splide = new Splide( '.splide' );
        splide.mount();
    </script>
    <section id="thumbnail-carousel" class="splide" style="margin-top: 10px; height: auto">
        <div class="splide__track">
            <ul class="splide__list" style="height:auto!important">
                <?php 
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach(get_field('gallery') as $image ) {
                        if ($i == 0) { $active = 'active'; } else { $active = '';}
                            echo '<li class="splide__slide" style="height:auto or 100%">';
                                echo '<img src="' . $image . '" style="width:100%; height: auto or 100%" />';
                            echo '</li>';
                            $i++;
                    }
                ?>
                    </ul>
              </div>
            
            </section>
            <style>
                .splide__list {
                    align-items: flex-start!important;
                    
                }
                .clear { clear: both; }
            </style>
            <script>
                document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                var main = new Splide( '#main-carousel', {
                    type      : 'loop',
                    rewind    : true,
                    pagination: false,
                    arrows    : false,
                    autoHeight: true,  
                    autoWidth: true,  
                    //autoplay : true, 
                    autoStart : true,
                    lazyLoad: true,  
                    perPage : 1,
                    perMove: 1,  
                    autoScroll: {
                        speed: 1,
                    },
                  } );

                  var thumbnails = new Splide( '#thumbnail-carousel', {
                    fixedWidth  : 100,
                    fixedHeight : 58,
                    gap         : 8,
                    rewind      : true,
                    pagination  : false,
                    isNavigation: true,
                    //autoHeight: true,
                    breakpoints : {
                      600: {
                        fixedWidth : 60,
                        fixedHeight: 44,
                      },
                    },
                  } );

                  main.sync( thumbnails );
                    
                  main.mount( window.splide.Extensions );
                  thumbnails.mount();

                } );
            </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: "...but just use the height of the taller image," [that's because you have ` autoHeight: true`](https://splidejs.com/guides/options/#autoheight). I can't offer a solution though; you didn't mention what you want your desired layout to be? Do the carousel need to have a fixed height and any images larger should fit to contain while preserving AR? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, autoHeight was a test (It just add `height:auto` style when generating the element), nothing change in the behavior. I don't need to preserve the AR, just the thumbanails staying attached to the bottom of the images and remove that blank space when a slide changes. So to clarify, If the image is 16:9 the thumbnails goes up, and if it's a 9:16 they go down.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/xd43y70p/ Note I didn't copy all your Splide settings. It takes the natural height of the image and applies it as the height of the slide. Let me know if that example in the jsfiddle is the behavior you want and I'll add a proper answer.

Comment: @Cooleronie Thanks for the help, I'm sorry but no, what I'm looking for, is an auto height image container, that move up the thumbnails if the image is smaller and move down if is taller staying glued to the bottom side of the picture.

Comment: I was confused because the example in my previous comment should exactly do what you described, but I saw it failed on the initial load because the Splidejs event `ready` fires before the (first) image is loaded. Fixed that, if it's still not you want I am clueless because this does exactly what you describe: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8frLmnxp/).

Comment: @Cooleronie Thanks, it just worked, just a little thing, getting this.naturalHeight() is not responsive, using this.clientHeight it's better. If you want to post as a reply, I can flag it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to dynamically change the [slide height](https://splidejs.com/guides/options/#height) using the height of the next image [before the carousel moves](https://splidejs.com/guides/events/#move) to keep the thumbnails 'glued' to the slider.

[Use the `Splide#on()` method](https://splidejs.com/guides/events/#listening-to-events) to listen to the `ready` event (to apply the first slide height) and the `move` event (to apply the slide height when the carousel moves).

To know which slide the carousel is moving to, use [the instance property `index`](https://splidejs.com/guides/apis/#index). To change the slide height, use [the property `options`](https://splidejs.com/guides/apis/#options).

```
var main = new Splide('#main-carousel');

main.on('ready', function() { 
  setHeightCarousel(0);  // index = 0
})

main.mount();

main.on('move', function() {
  const currentIndex = main.index;
  setHeightCarousel(currentIndex);
})
```

And here's how `setHeightCarousel(index)` could look like. Note I added the class `splide__img` in the HTML on each `<img>` tag to target them.

```
function setHeightCarousel(index) {
  const image = document.querySelectorAll('.splide__img')[index];
  let imgHeight;
  if (image.complete) {
      imgHeight = image.naturalHeight;
      main.options = {
        height: imgHeight + 'px'
      }        
  } else {
      image.addEventListener('load', function() {
        imgHeight = this.naturalHeight;
        main.options = {
          height: imgHeight + 'px'
        }          
      })
  }
}
```

Because the `ready` event [fires before the image is loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) the function first checks whether the image is loaded, and if not adds [a load event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event). A callback or promise is purposefully avoided here, but can be used to improve the code depending on the implementation.

[The `naturalHeight` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight) is used to get the intrinsic height of the image, in the presumption you might want to (down)scale the image first.

##### Here's a working example in a JSFiddle using Splide V4.1.4.

Or view it in a snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var main = new Splide('#main-carousel', {
    type: 'fade',
    rewind: true,
    pagination: false,
    arrows: false,
    lazyLoad: 'sequential'
  })

  var thumbnails = new Splide('#thumbnail-carousel', {
    fixedWidth: 100,
    fixedHeight: 60,
    gap: 10,
    rewind: true,
    pagination: false,
    isNavigation: true,
    breakpoints: {
      600: {
        fixedWidth: 60,
        fixedHeight: 44,
      },
    }
  })

  main.on('ready', function() {
    setHeightCarousel(0);
  })

  main.sync(thumbnails);
  main.mount();
  thumbnails.mount();

  main.on('move', function() {
    const currentIndex = main.index;
    setHeightCarousel(currentIndex);
  })

  function setHeightCarousel(index) {
    const image = document.querySelectorAll('.splide__img')[index];
    let imgHeight;
    if (image.complete) {
        imgHeight = image.naturalHeight;
        main.options = {
          height: imgHeight + 'px'
        }        
    } else {
        image.addEventListener('load', function() {
          imgHeight = this.naturalHeight;
          main.options = {
            height: imgHeight + 'px'
          }          
        })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 1rem 1rem;
}

#thumbnail-carousel .splide__track .splide__list .splide__slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* Centers the image */
/*
.splide__slide img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
} 
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/css/splide.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <section id="main-carousel" class="splide" aria-label="Beautiful Images">
    <div class="splide__track">
      <ul class="splide__list">
        <li class="splide__slide">
          <div class="splide__slide__container">
            <img data-splide-lazy="https://via.placeholder.com/250x140" alt="" class="splide__img">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="splide__slide">
          <div class="splide__slide__container">
            <img data-splide-lazy="https://via.placeholder.com/140x250" alt="" class="splide__img">
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="splide__slide">
        <div class="splide__slide__container">
          <img data-splide-lazy="https://via.placeholder.com/250x140" alt="" class="splide__img">
        </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="thumbnail-carousel" class="splide">
    <div class="splide__track">
      <ul class="splide__list">
        <li class="splide__slide">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x140" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="splide__slide">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x250" alt="">
        </li>
        <li class="splide__slide">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x140" alt="">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

**A few notes.**

1. > To make [lazy load](https://splidejs.com/guides/options/#lazyload) work, the img element in the slide must have the data-splide-lazy attribute that indicates the path or URL to the source file.
2. By changing the height of the slider and therefore the position of the thumbnails you are shifting the layout. This is generally considered poor UX and [can be measured using the Cumulative Layout Shift](https://web.dev/cls/). Alternatives are to position the thumbnails on top or aside the main carousel, or by centering the 16:9 image (leaving white-space around it versus just below it).